# React date pickers use older react versions

Tags: reactjs, datetime, react-datetime

I am creating application which use a calendar and tried several react-date time pickers such as react-jqueryui-datepicker , react-date-picker-cs
issue is those libraries use different old react versions and they give react older version errors,
my application is created from react creat-app skeleton 
what are the options that i can try to solve this

Comment: [`react-datepicker` has React 16 as a `peerDependency`](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/93c46ed1c0ced5d110ea8d80efc0df9ef8764e13/package.json#L87). That should work fine.

Comment: yes found that , have to edit my question , earlier i was tried react-jquery-datepicker, any idea on using those packages

Comment: Haven't used any of those, so not sure. Have you tried `react-datepicker`? It might suit your needs.

Comment: i started using it and it  loads fine ,will try to do the requirement from that one, thanks

Comment: yes it worked @Tholle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`react-datepicker` has React 16 as a `peerDependency`](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/93c46ed1c0ced5d110ea8d80efc0df9ef8764e13/package.json#L87) which should work fine for your needs.